# SwiftyJson and Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to combine Alamofire and SwiftJSON, but every tutorial I have followed does not work. Here is my code:

```
request(.GET, "http://api.randomuser.me", parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
            if(error != nil) {

            }
            else {
                var json = JSON(json!)
                if let cell = json[0]["results"]["cell"]["registered"].string{
                    //Now you got your value
                    println(cell)
                }
                else
                {
                    println("error")
                }

            }

    }
```

I just want to get the cell phone number from the json data. The JSON returns in the following format:

```
{
"results" : [
{
  "seed" : "85a9f46b169c1d3f",
  "user" : {
    "sha256" : "bd60a88fb92ee4b50c51b2e22acd2196e5b1b0317fbbd97d1c554d2437abc577",
    "cell" : "(699)-992-8562",
    "phone" : "(810)-927-4340",
    "version" : "0.5",
    "SSN" : "140-22-8290",
    "nationality" : "US",
    "sha1" : "23a62834c34efdc8fab5e02c47a96d204f18bad7",
    "registered" : "1289959546",
    "dob" : "101759680",
    "picture" : {
      "large" : "http:\/\/api.randomuser.me\/portraits\/women\/2.jpg",
      "thumbnail" : "http:\/\/api.randomuser.me\/portraits\/thumb\/women\/2.jpg",
      "medium" : "http:\/\/api.randomuser.me\/portraits\/med\/women\/2.jpg"
    },
    "location" : {
      "state" : "mississippi",
      "street" : "8718 marsh ln",
      "city" : "las vegas",
      "zip" : "34685"
    },
    "password" : "molson",
    "salt" : "SFdoIQnc",
    "username" : "silverladybug271",
    "md5" : "8f15f0d67a9e7610312dc8e62c766943",
    "email" : "felecia.andrews12@example.com",
    "gender" : "female",
    "name" : {
      "title" : "mrs",
      "first" : "felecia",
      "last" : "andrews"
    }
  }
}
]
}
```

When I try to print `cell` it returns nil. Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
request(.GET, "http://api.randomuser.me", parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
            if(error != nil) {

            }
            else {
                var json = JSON(json!)
                if let cell = json["results"][0]["user"]["cell"].string{
                    //Now you got your value
                    println(cell)
                }
                else
                {
                    println("error")
                }

            }

    }
```

The problem was that you had ordered the subscripts incorrectly: you need first to access the value of the "results" key, next you need the first item in the array, and so on.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon the [0] is moved after ["results"]

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow would you please put that into your answer as well? Your solution is obviously working great, but it takes a while to go through three "walls of text" to see what is going on in here. Just simple explanation what the OP got wrong.